# AWS data pipeline VS lambda for EMR automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-data-pipeline

Here are the steps for my application in AWS .

1. Data will be loaded weekly in separate 35  `S3` folders .
2. On completion of data loading in each 35 folders 35 EMR cluster will be created .
3. Each EMR cluster will have spark-scala script to run parrelly .
4. On completion of job all cluster will be terminated .

How can i achieve this ?

As far as i have searched there are two options .

1. Invoking `AWS lambda` function on S3 event and lambda will create EMR cluster and will do spark-submit .
2. I read about AWS data pipeline .

Will `AWS Data pipeline` will be helpful in my scenario ?

Also i have spark-scala script that i have been running zeppelin .
If required i can create jar out of that and submit in data pipe line .

Please consider the cost also .I have 5TB of data to be delivered to client weekly .

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use Data pipelines. The pipelines will take care of the EMR creation, submission of the job and shutting down the EMR once processing is completed. You can specify the steps for EMR in the "activity" section. "Resource" section can specify the parameters of the EMR cluster (like instance type/role to use etc)

You can even configure an alert - to send you an email via SNS if the pipeline fails for some reason.

Now coming to the part about how to trigger the pipeline. If the data coming in is at predetermined times, you could consider using "schedule" in the pipeline. The pipeline will then activate at the specified time every day/week/month.

Comment: Yes Data will come periodically ..Also we can invoke 10 emr cluster parallel.But how is it better than lambda invoking EMR ?

Comment: Well, both can do what you want. The difference is mainly in the ease of setting them up.

With Pipelines everything is GUI based so you can pick and choose to create your pipeline.

With Lambda, you will need python expertise to code the flow along with error handling to create the EMR using boto3 framework.

Lots of features are inbuilt in pipelines compared to Lambda. Example - For periodic execution with lambda you will need to create a separate trigger in cloudwatch events. In Pipeline, schedule is inbuilt.

Comment: Great ,So i can create Pipeline once in UI and utilize that every time we want ?Once EMR job is finished Pipeline will be terminated ?

Comment: No, once the EMR job is completed, EMR is shutdown. But, pipeline remains active. If scheduled, it will trigger an EMR at the said time automatically. Once the pipeline is created and is working fine, you don't need to fiddle with it anymore.